# Find a bijection to prove a fact about integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Prove that for fixed positive integers $k$ and $n$, the number of partitions of $n$ is equal to the number of partitions of $2n + k$ into $n + k$ parts.

I tried this with different values of n but can't seem to get a bijection between the two partitions.

Answer (score 2):

let $n=a_1+a_2+ \cdots +a_j$ be a partition of $n$ then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2n+k= (a_1+1)+(a_2+1)+\cdots +(a_j+1) + \underbrace{1+1+ \cdots +1}_{\text{$n+k-j$  ones}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is this a sufficient proof? how can I prove it is indeed a bijection?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to show that this mapping is one-one and onto (and therefore a bijection). This is easy to show ... ?